# Send an email with a button with no form

Tags: javascript, html, email

Sorry, I have no code that needs fixing, but I'm here to find out if it's possible to do something.

I want the option so when a user clicks Request data it sends an email to 'example@example.com' with a pre-defined message, and then the user gets a message to say the email has sent.

Has anyone done something like this before that can share the code? Tried looking on CodePen but can't find anything.

Comment: actually there´s sth. https://www.smtpjs.com/

Comment: in the browser or node?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "mailto" to achieve this.

Haven't tested but you can try this:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=Mail from Our Site&body=body-goes-here">Email Us</a>
```

*Going off of [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/)*